# Get item from localstorage using javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got an object in my local storage and need a part of it. Now how can i get that part?

**Key**

`Test`

**Value**

`[{"ID":nr, "name": name, "age": nr },{ "ID":nr, "name": name, "age": nr}]`

I would like to use the both ages and then use the name of the oldest of those 2.

// Retrieve the object from storage

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('Test');

console.log('typeof retrievedObject: ' + typeof retrievedObject);
console.log('Value of retrievedObject: ' + retrievedObject);
```

The console output is

```
"typeof retrievedObject: string"
"Value of retrievedObject: [{"ID":1, "name": Test1, "age": 10 },{ "ID":2, "name": Test2, "age": 8}]"
```

---

Using JSON.parse

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('Test');
var obj= JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

console.log(typeof obj);
console.log( obj);
```

The console output is

```
"object"  
Array [ Object, Object ]
```

Comment: Local storage only stores strings, so if you want to store an object/array you should use `JSON.stringify()` and then when you retrieve it use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: I did use JSON.stringify() so to recieve the data I should use JSON.parse? I'm just starting with javascript and localstorage. Thx for the info

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you should understand that what you really have stored with the key "Test" is a serialized/stringified JSON table with two records/rows. Therefore, after retrieving the stringified table you have to deserialize it with `JSON.parse` before you can access its records.

I have described how to store database tables in the form of "JSON tables" with locaLStorage in [Chapter 2 Storing Data with JavaScript's LocalStorage API](http://oxygen.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/webeng/JsFrontendApp/minimal-tutorial.html#d5e660) in my article "JavaScript Frontend Web Apps Tutorial Part 1: Building a Minimal App in Seven Steps", which explains how to manage book data using locaLStorage.